# Como salvar no banco as opções de checkbox?

Tags: php, mysql

Preciso salvar as frutas e os valores em campos diferente no banco"

PHP:

```
<?php
   session_start();
   //if (!isset($_SESSION["usuario"])){echo "<script>alert('O SEU INGRESSO É VALIDO');window.location=\"index.php\";</script>";}
   include "funciones.php";
   date_default_timezone_set("America/Sao_Paulo");

   if (isset($_POST["edit_fruta_x"])){

      $_SESSION["idrelatorio"]=$_POST["relatorio"];//Se o usuário escolheu da lista um projeto     para diagnosticar, guardo o seu IDprojeto para referenciar
      $_SESSION["idbanca"]=$_POST["banca"];
      $_SESSION["idfruta"]=$_POST["fruta"];

      unset($_POST["fruta"]);

      lerbanca($_SESSION['idbanca']);//procura os dados da banca escolhida
      lerlocalizacao($_SESSION["idrelatorio"]);
   }

   else{
      $_SESSION["idrelatorio"]=$_POST["relatorio"];
      $_SESSION["idbanca"]=$_POST["banca"];

      lerlocalizacao($_SESSION["idrelatorio"]);
      unset($_SESSION['idfruta']);
      unset($_SESSION['fruta']);
   }

?>
```

HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   }
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form class="form-signin" action='salvafrutas.php' method="post">

<label>bancas de frutas</label>
<!-- 1.1 salvar frutas   -->
<label>1. Lista de Frutas</label>

<table>
<!-- lista que seleciona as ações do botão para saber se está marcado ou não-->
<tr><th colspan=3><b>1.Tipo de frutas</b></th></tr>
<tr><th colspan=2>Características</td><th colspan=2>valores</th></tr>
<tr><td colspan=2>1. uva</td><td><input id="uva" type="checkbox"     name="comportamento[]" value="6"  <?php if(isset($_SESSION['comportamento'])){echo (strpos($_SESSION['comportamento'],'6')!==false) ? 'checked="checked"' : '';}?> onclick="apaga_nao1(this)"> 6 </td></tr>
<tr><td colspan=2>2. banana</td><td><input id="banana" type="checkbox" name="comportamento[]" value="0" <?php if(isset($_SESSION['comportamento'])){echo (strpos($_SESSION['comportamento'],'0')!==false) ? 'checked="checked"' : '';}?> onclick="apaga_nao1(this)"> 0 </td></tr>
<tr><td colspan=2>3. maça</td><td><input id="maça" type="checkbox" name="comportamento[]" value="3" <?php if(isset($_SESSION['comportamento'])){echo (strpos($_SESSION['comportamento'],'3')!==false) ? 'checked="checked"' : '';}?> onclick="apaga_nao1(this)"> 3 </td></tr>
<tr><td colspan=2>4. pera</td><td><input id="pera" type="checkbox" name="comportamento[]" value="4" <?php if(isset($_SESSION['comportamento'])){echo (strpos($_SESSION['comportamento'],'')!==false) ? 'checked="checked"' : '';}?> onclick="apaga_nao1(this)"> 4 </td> </tr>
</table>
<br>
<!--<button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Salvar</button> -->  
<input id='btgravar' type='image' src="salvar.png" title='SALVAR' width='70' height='70'/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Boa, ficou mais claro! Já dei o meu voto para reabrir. O que quer gravar na BD? Quando tem no HTML `name="comportamento[]"` isso vai fazer com que no PHP chegue uma array onde tem valores do `value` do HTML. Ou seja, se alguém escolher todas as checkboxes vai ter algo como `array(6, 0, 3,4);`, é isso que quer guardar na BD ou quer o nome da fruta também? Pode explicar melhor toda a informação que quer salvar nd BD desse formulário?

Comment: Você precisa fazer um array com o nome das frutas, interligado ao código que você atribuiu no value do seu select html.  Exemplo: $frutas = array(0=>"banana", 3=>"maca", 4=>"pera", 6=>"uva"); $nomedafruta = $frutas[$_POST["comportamento"]]; (apenas exemplo, é necessário fazer um foreach no $_POST["comportamento"] pra poder pegar todos os marcados...)

Comment: Então @MarianaGomes - Dentro do foreach, se você tiver feito a array $frutas como eu disse (declare no inicio do seu php), você terá a fruta com $frutas[$value]... Se você quer o conteúdo separado por /, voce precisa fazer: 
    $comporta['comportamento'] .= $value.":".$frutas[$value]."/"; 
Dessa forma voce terá o numero selecionado, dois pontos (:), e o nome da fruta, seguido de uma barra (/).

Comment: Bom dia Mariana, pode responder á minha pergunta/comentário em cima?

Comment: @Sergio, eu preciso salvar as frutas e os valores, mas em campos diferentes no banco de dados.

Answer (score 2):

Tanto campos `CheckBox` quanto campos `RadioButton` servem de um mesmo proposito, eu tenho um exemplo que faço da seguinte forma:

HTML:

```
DES2 <input type="checkbox" name="motivo[]" id="DES2" onclick="checar(this.id)" value="0" />
DES3 <input type="checkbox" name="motivo[]" id="DES3" onclick="checar(this.id)" value="0" />
DES4 <input type="checkbox" name="motivo[]" id="DES4" onclick="checar(this.id)" value="0" />
```

JS:

```
function checar(idObj) {
    val = idObj;
    idObj = "#" + idObj;
    if ($(idObj).is(':checked')) {
        $(idObj).val(val);
    } else {
        $(idObj).val(0);
    }
}
```

Como é enviado ao dar submit no formulário:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Explicando... eu envio em forma de array e faço o tratamento no PHP como segue abaixo...

PHP:

```
    $_POST["DES2"] = 0;
    $_POST["DES3"] = 0;
    $_POST["DES4"] = 0;

    $checkBox = $_POST['motivo'];
    if ($checkBox) {
        $i = 0;
        foreach ( $checkBox as $value ) {
            switch ($value) {
                case "DES2" :
                    $_POST["DES2"] = 1;
                    break;
                case "DES3" :
                    $_POST["DES3"] = 1;
                    break;
                case "DES4" :
                    $_POST["DES4"] = 1;
                    break;
                default :break;
                $i++;
            }
        }
    }
```

O modo como você salva no banco fica a seu critério....

Existem outros modos de fazer isso, as vezes até mais fáceis... porém depende da sua implementação, dos padrões da empresa e talz